# PCIe SSD not recognized, only when restarting on iMac

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac, ssd

I have an iMac 2019,2 that I installed an 2T Aura Pro X2 into the PCIe SSD slot, and I left the original Apple 1T HDD drive in the SATA slot.
I was able to:

- Successfully split up the Fusion Drive using [the answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346516/how-do-i-split-fusion-drive-on-mojave-apfs).
- Successfully format the SSD with Sonoma and mark it as the start-up disk.
- Successfully format the HDD as an empty APFS drive

After "shutdown", the computer starts up successfully to the new SSD.

My problem is that after "restart", the iMac is not able to see the new SSD and gives the "flashing question mark folder" screen.

The same is true for recovery mode - if I boot into recovery mode from a shutdown state, Disk Utility and `diskutil` can see the new SSD.  If I boot into recovery mode after a restart, Disk Utility and `diskutil` do NOT see the new SSD.

I even tried installing Sonoma on the HDD, verified that it worked starting up from both shutdown and restart, and then cloned that to the SSD using `dd` in the terminal (booting up from an external drive).  The behavior is the same (can't see the SSD after a "restart").

I have installed Sonoma 14.3 on the SSD, and I've booted into bootable installers for every macOS from Catalina onwards - the behavior is the same.  What could be causing this and how do I fix the situation so that the computer boots up to the new SSD regardless of whether it is shutdown or restarted?

Comment: What version of macOS was installed when you were using a Fusion Drive arrangement with the Apple SSD? Have you tried a Fusion Drive arrangement with the new SSD? If so, then how much of the HDD was allocated to the Fusion Drive?

Comment: Have you tried [OWC support](https://www.owc.com/support)?

Comment: The OS being used while it was Fusion was Sonoma, as well (maybe 14.1).  It was running crazy slow for a long time before I decided to try and upgrade the Hard Drives.  I have not yet tried a Fusion Drive arrangement with the new SSD, as I was hoping to maximize the speed of the new set-up, but that would be worth trying.

Comment: Yes, I am working with OWC Support, as well - but we are running out of things to try.